# Is it considered pythonic and/or good practice to concatenate strings with curly braces instead of the + operator?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

Curly brace concatenation:

```
name = "John"
surname = "Doe"
print(f"Hello {name} {surname}.")
```

(+) operator concatenation:

```
name = "John"
surname = "Doe"
print("Hello" + " " + name + " " + surname + '.')
```

In the online courses I've looked into they all explain using the (+) operator to concatenate strings.
Are the curly braces considered inferior and/or bad practice?

Comment: F-strings are new in Python 3, and many online courses may not have been updated.  I'd consider the first example with the f-strings to be much easier to read -- as a rule of thumb I tend to go with whatever makes for the shortest line of code.

Comment: f-strings are Python 3.6, so they are rather new. You'll not find too many examples with them. IMHO, f-strings are easier to read, especially if you have an IDE that does syntax highlighting for you

Comment: To expand a little -- if you're just concatenating two strings, I'd use `+`.  `foo + bar` is simpler than `f"{foo}{bar}"`.  Once you have something more complicated than two or  or three strings, or you're mixing objects of different types that you'd need to call `str()` to convert, f-strings are cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

f string were introduced in Python 3, so courses may have not updated it. And, Using ¨+¨ is easier to understand for beginners. I still use them.

Comment: They are new in Python 3.6. If you need to be compatible to <3.6 this could be a no-go.

Comment: Yes, that is also true.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "curly brace concatenation" is actually a "f-string", introduced in python 3.6. It's more readable and less error prone when you have to concatenate strings and variables. It is also faster, because it's evaluated at run-time. So if you have pyhton>3.6 it's definitively better to use f-strings. You can better read [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) in details.